# Error 424: object required when calling external library

Tags: vba

I'm writing a VBA macro, and have imported mscorlib.dll in order to refer to System.Math.

```
Sub draw16mmButtonHole()
    Dim test As Double
    test = System.Math.ASin(0) 'this is where the error happens
End Sub
```

Apparently Error 424 usually happens when calls return objects, and can be fixed by appending `set` to the variable assignment; however, here the same error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the behavior described above, Error 424 happens when trying to call .NET functions from VBA. This is not something VBA is able to do.